# Advice regarding Unity hosted content

Tags: unity

I'm currently trying to build a mobile application that, for the purposes of trying to keep small in size, I would like to have store much of its content Online and be downloaded to the users mobile when the application requires it.

Ideally I'd like to do so not just as a means to reduce the applications original size, but also to allow new assets to be introduced over time (such as new objects and textures) without the user having to reinstall the application or download a new update.

I am at the moment researching into the use of Unitys Addressible Assets for these purposes, and am currently trying to test and implement this idea on a small scale using assets stored using Google Cloud storage.

If possible however I would like to to ask whether anyone here has any experience with storing and accessing assets on an external server, and if so, might they have any advice as to whether or not this could be a feasible solution for these purposes?

Any help would be really appreciated, as this is an area that is completely new to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is one of the main purposes of Addressables, is it not? In what specific way are you concerned this might be not feasible? What specific problem do you need advice about how to overcome?

Comment: Hi DMGregory, Yeah this was how I came to look into using addressable assets, however I've been having trouble finding any information Online regarding whether or not this is workable for a fairly large android game and not simply for adding a few assets to an existing application. I'm currently working through some tutorials for setting up a hosting site and implementing this within Unity, however was ideally looking to see if anyone had any first-hand experience using Unitys Addressible functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I need to be more specific in terms of what problem I am facing.  If anyone has used Unitys addressable asset functionality, I'd like to know if possible the following : 1.) Could this be used to load individual levels and assets of a fairly large android game, or would loading times be too much of an issue 2.) Are there any limitations to using addressable assets that would be useful to know about with regards to loading data to an android device.

Comment: Question 1 is best answered by your own profiling. Look at the size of an Android game of the scale you're thinking of. Copy and paste some placeholder assets until you have a similar file size in total. Try downloading with Addressables from your hosting service and measure the loading time. Now you have a concrete number to compare against your goals, and you know it's real, not just hearsay from an Internet stranger. Question 2 is a bit too broad and hazy for our Q&A structure here. How would we judge a complete & correct answer? If the answer were "no, you're good to go," how to prove it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, and yes I do apologize for the slight vague nature of my second question.

Comment: So, can you edit your question above to make it less vague/more focused, and I can delete this comment thread? Or would you prefer to put the question on hold until you've completed your profiling and have a clearer whether what you have is already sufficient for your game?